# golang append syntax error: missing statement after label

Tags: go, append

```
    fmt.Print("Text to send: ")
    text, _ := readerConsole.ReadString('\n')

    sizen := (int)(unsafe.Sizeof(text))
    fmt.Print(sizen)
    var bs []byte
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(bs, sizen)

    b := []byte(text)
    a: = append(bs, b...)
```

Go formatter says error
"syntax error: missing statement after label" on append

Comment: Remove the space in `: =`

Comment: yeah! thats works! thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's syntax error mate. Should be `a := append(bs, b...)` mate.